# datagridview not autoresizing properly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to autosize my dgv's width and height,
However, it leaves me with big spaces in width, something isn't right.

This is the code I'm using:

```
int height = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    height += row.Height;
}
height += dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight;

int width = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
{
    width += col.Width;
}
width += dgv.RowHeadersWidth;

dgv.ClientSize = new Size(width + 2, height + 2);
```

[dgv with spaces in width -  example 1](http://image.prntscr.com/image/1cf9d102ef314fc9bdd88cb7bbe563ba.png)

[dgv with spaces in width -  example 2](http://image.prntscr.com/image/d8806060d9bb45f595fb95e299348590.png)

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to define its height/width? Usually that will be done by the control itself.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode`. You can also force a resize with `DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();` then.

You just added all column widths together but who says that the column widths are as desired?

Comment: What you suggested didn't work.

Here is a screenshot after i tried what you suggested : 

http://image.prntscr.com/image/8b8101edc5c04065bfc4d1a808632e95.png

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Maybe you use my suggestion wrong. What values did you use for `AutoSizeColumnsMode`? Where did you call `AutoResizeColumns()`?

Comment: I tried all the values for AutoSizeColumnsMode() , and i used AutoResizeColumns() in the Form load method.

Comment: I assume you called `AutoResizeColumns` after you filled the grid with rows and columns. And I also assume you removed/commented your code above so it can't interfere with the auto sizing. Am I right?

Comment: Each column has its own `AutoSizeMode` property. Try to set it to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells` for each column (you can do this inside the Designer's property table). You can set the `AutoSize` mode for the last column to `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill` if desired. This should work.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24877756/DGVAutoSizeCol.png

Comment: thank you for your help , i forgot to mention that the data is imported from access database (the table is blank before runtime)

Comment: I guess you can still iterate all columns and set their `AutoSizeMode` after the grid is filled. If setting the `AutoSizeMode` has no effect, try an additional `AutoResizeColumns()` afterwards. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I need to do this using code 
( i mean use for loop and run on the columns of the DataGridView )?

Comment: Exactly. Try `foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
            {
                col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            }
dgv.AutoResizeColumns();`

Comment: I've tried what you suggested , but it still dosen't work. 

screenshot of the code :  http://image.prntscr.com/image/4e8e660a31c04e83aad89e26ea353288.png 

, screenshot of the datagridview after i ran your code :

http://image.prntscr.com/image/a6910de2e8474d7abf68b3dc9cc2c925.png

Comment: It would be interesting at what time you run this code. Usually this should work. It also works for me. I have tested it. So I guess you call it at the wrong time or you have some code anywhere else that messes up the column widths again. If nothing works you can store the column widths after you called my last code, set the `AutoSizeMode` to `None` and then set the column widths again with the stored values. But in my opinion this should not be necessary.

Comment: You also can try the debugger and look how the `DataGridView` looks after the above code was executed. At this time the `DataGridView` should also be filled with values.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `DataGridView` defines that properties by itself.
They got the properties `ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode` which you can set to `AutoSize`.

With `AutoSizeColumnsMode` you can even tell the `DataGridView` which Object needs to resize. (Like `ColumnHeader`, `AllCellsExceptHeader`, `AllCells`.

You can find those easily in the Property Window. No need to Code that.

Comment: What you suggested didn't work.

Here is a screenshot after i tried what you suggested : 


http://image.prntscr.com/image/8b8101edc5c04065bfc4d1a808632e95.png

Comment: What exactly didn't work? As much as I can see, the columns and rows are not too small and everything is readable.